# MKMapViewDelegate method "mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)" not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have taken outlet of `Mapview` and set delegate to self. Also conformed to protocol MKMapViewDelegate

```
@IBOutlet weak var theMapView: MKMapView!
...
theMapView.delegate = self

let addAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
addAnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: xxx, longitude: yyyy)

theMapView.addAnnotation(addAnotation)
```

What I may be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't posted enough code.

Comment: Also you need to post the code in context

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

Turned out providing invalid values of longitude and latitude in `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: xxx, longitude: yyyy)` was causing it.

After trying some other values of lat and long from google, delegate method is now getting called.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
..
}
```

Comment: You didn't specified the values which caused the problem. You also didn't specified what you mean with none invalid numbers.